# How do I persist the original timezone in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Specifically in SQL server (and I'm assuming others), there is a datetimeoffset type that can store the timestamp with an offset *other* than GMT. (Looks like this "1998-01-01 15:00:00.0000000 +06:00")

But trying to persist a Calendar to the database automatically converts it to GMT (although I can't tell who's doing it JPA, Hibernate, or sqljdbc) so it looks like this "1998-01-01 9:00:00.0000000 +00:00"

Is there a way to prevent this for certain attributes?

Comment: is there any reason, why you want to use another offset than UTC (=GMT)?

Comment: Yes, I want to remember the offset that was given to me. So that when i email it back it's in the same offset. (I want the customer to see it in their timezone, not GMT, not mine.) I still want to save the offset though because I have to run calculations against other values in this table that happen to be in different timezones.

Comment: have I understood correctly, you dont want tu use UTC as reference?, so GMT + 6.0 is not desired? You want another reference, like EST + 03:00 ?

Comment: no the " +6:00" at the end IS desired, but whenever I persist to the database it changes the hour and makes it " +0:00"

Answer (score 2):

Altough there might be other solutions using SQL databases, I always follow this approach:

In a data base or file I always store times in UTC, with no exception.
If the timezone has to be preserved, e.g for UI, then I store the UTC offset in an extra field.

This way I have the correct time, and if needded the time zone is preserved.

Comment: Alex I can't just tell a company to rip out a tenured SQL table "on principal". Hence why I asked how to properly use the datetimeoffset provided in SQL through JPA interface. If I had asked about the proper design for the table then your answer would be perfectly contextual. But as it stand you offer no solution to my current problem by simply saying it shouldn't be done. As it turns out, I was able to come up with a fairly simple solution.

Comment: @mike I offer a solution for all others that are able to define/change their data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do it

```
package testers.jpa.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name = "dbo.tester")
//Ignore the actual calendar object here because the jsonner strips the timezone info from it
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "date" })
@NamedQuery(name = "NameAndOffset.purge", query = "DELETE FROM NameAndOffset")
public class NameAndOffset implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private Calendar date;

    public NameAndOffset() {

    }

    public NameAndOffset(String name, Calendar date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Id
    @Basic
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Return a string representation of the {@link NameAndOffset#date} object.<br/>
     * This will be used by JPA and the Jsonner to prevent losing the timezone
     * information<br/>
     * <br/>
     * For this to work properly you must tell both the Json mapper and JPA to
     * ignore anything else that relates to the {@link NameAndOffset#date} field
     * 
     * @return A String representation of the {@link NameAndOffset#date} field,
     *         formatted for SQL Server's datetimeoffset data type
     */
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "date")
    public String getDateTimeOffset() {
        return new OffsetDateFormat().formatCalendar(date);
    }

    public void setDateTimeOffset(String date) throws ParseException {
        this.date = new OffsetDateFormat().parseCalendar(date);
    }

    //Ignore the actual calendar object here because JPA strips the timezone info from it
    @Transient
    public Calendar getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Calendar date) throws ParseException {
        this.date = date;
    }

    class OffsetDateFormat extends SimpleDateFormat {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final String OFFSET_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S Z";

        public OffsetDateFormat() {
            super(OFFSET_FORMAT);
        }

        public Calendar parseCalendar(String source) throws ParseException {
            //pull out the colon in the offset
            int timeZoneColon = source.lastIndexOf(":");
            String nocolon = source.substring(0, timeZoneColon) + source.substring(timeZoneColon + 1);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            cal.setTime(parse(nocolon));
            //after parsing, the timezone of this DateFormatter changes to whatever was represented in the string
            //make sure the new calendar reflects this
            cal.setTimeZone(getTimeZone());
            return cal;
        }

        public String formatCalendar(Calendar calendar) {
            setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());
            String nocolon = format(calendar.getTime());

            //add the colon
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(nocolon.substring(0, nocolon.length() - 2)).append(":").append(nocolon.substring(nocolon.length() - 2));

            return sb.toString();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: the problem of this solution is if you have to use between or any other query to filter the date, because it is stored as String in you database.